# How to obtain screen size from xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using wpf on C# to design GUI, and I want to get screen size (The value of Width and Height) from xaml code.

I knew how to get them from C# code as

```
   Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
   Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

But I don't know how to get them from `XAML` code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will work.  You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) about SystemParameters

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 10):

Check out the SystemParameters class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.systemparameters.fullprimaryscreenheight.aspx

You can use it like this:

```
<Object Attribute="{x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}"/>
```

(You could also use the x:Static notation to query the Windows Forms properties, however if you're developing a WPF application the SystemParameters class might be the way to go)

Answer (score 2):

Say your parent container in the XAML is grid, name it as grdForm

In the code behind can get the dimensions as

double width=grdForm.ActualWidth

double height=grdForm.ActualHeight