# How can i make Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From 100 To fullscreen to adapt all screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I make `Storyboard.TargetProperty=“Width”` From 100 To fullscreen to adapt all screen?

I want to set it to fullscreen, not 500.

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded" >
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:02" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="500"  To="100" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain screen size from xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416561/how-to-obtain-screen-size-from-xaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 500 use

```
{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}
```

Comment: Thanks！This is userful!