# System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth throws NullReferenceException sometimes

Tags: wpf

```
double width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

The above two lines throw NullReferenceException sometimes?
Is there any better way to get screen resolution in WPF?

Edit:
Just realize that these two properties are double and a double can never be null. 
But the stack trace points to these two lines.

Comment: Is this maybe what you are looking for ? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416561/how-to-obtain-screen-size-from-xaml>

Comment: My question is why I am getting NullRefereneceException here? and what is causing it? your link does not answer that.

Comment: you right double can never be null, can you check is SystemParameters null? :)

Comment: SystemParameters is a static class, i.e. can not be null.